# TypeError: descriptor 'strftime' requires a 'datetime.date' object but received a 'Text'

Tags: python, datetime

I have a variable `testeddate` which has a date in text format like 4/25/2015. I am trying convert it to `%Y-%m-%d %H:%M:%S` as follows:

```
dt_str = datetime.strftime(testeddate,'%Y-%m-%d %H:%M:%S')
```

but I am running into this error:

```
TypeError: descriptor 'strftime' requires a 'datetime.date' object but received a 'Text'
```

How do I resolve this?

Comment: `datetime.strftime` is not a static method, you need to call it on an actual `datetime` object: https://docs.python.org/2/library/datetime.html#datetime.date.strftime

Comment: @jonny - that means I should use something like datetime.datetime.strftime

Comment: See [`strftime()` and `strptime()` Behavior](https://docs.python.org/2/library/datetime.html#strftime-and-strptime-behavior)

Comment: @user2125827: First, yes, technically, you _can_ write `datetime.datetime.strftime(dt, fmt)` instead of `dt.strftime(fmt)`, just like you can write `str.encode(s, encoding)` instead of `s.encode(encoding)`. But it's more idiomatic, more readable, and more concise to write `dt.strftime(fmt)`. And, more importantly, you don't actually have a `datetime` in the first place, you seem to be mixing up `strftime` (`f` for **format**) and `strptime` (`p` for **parse**); they're opposites.

Answer (score 37, accepted):

You have a `Text` object. The [`strftime`](https://docs.python.org/2/library/time.html#time.strftime) function requires a datetime object. The code below takes an intermediate step of converting your `Text` to a `datetime` using [`strptime`](https://docs.python.org/2/library/time.html#time.strptime)

```
import datetime
testeddate = '4/25/2015'
dt_obj = datetime.datetime.strptime(testeddate,'%m/%d/%Y')
```

At this point, the `dt_obj` is a datetime object. This means we can easily convert it to a string with any format. In your particular case:

```
dt_str = datetime.datetime.strftime(dt_obj,'%Y-%m-%d %H:%M:%S')
```

The `dt_str` now is:

```
'2015-04-25 00:00:00'
```

Comment: Or can use just: dt_str = datetime.strptime(testeddate,'%m/%d/%Y').strftime('%Y-%m-%d %H:%M:%S') , assuming that the import is: from datetime import datetime

Comment: I get an error `AttributeError: type object 'datetime.datetime' has no attribute 'datetime'` at line `dt_obj = datetime.datetime.strptime(testeddate,'%m/%d/%Y')`

Comment: What is your import statement? If you are just going `import datetime` it will work as I have it. If you are doing `from datetime import datetime` change that line to `dt_obj = datetime.strptime(testeddate,'%m/%d/%Y')`

Comment: You are putting in the first place the object and in the second one the format and works. However, I saw everywhere else that first comes the format and then the object `strftime("%a, %d %b %Y %H:%M:%S +0000", gmtime())`and I was getting an error all the time. What am I missing?

Answer (score 0):

A less elegant solution would involve manipulating the string directly.

```
testeddate = '4/25/2015'
month, day, year = testeddate.split('/')
testeddate = '-'.join([year, month, day]) + ' 00:00:00'
```

Answer (score -1):

The error message you're encountering, `TypeError: descriptor 'strftime' requires a 'datetime.date' object but received a 'Text'`, indicates that the `strftime` method is expecting a `datetime.date` object, but you're providing it with a text string.

To resolve this, you first need to convert the text string into a `datetime.date` object before using the `strftime` method.

```py
from datetime import datetime

testeddate = '4/25/2015'

# Convert the string to a datetime object i.e,
# converted to datetime.datetime(2015, 4, 25, 0, 0)
datetime_obj = datetime.strptime(testeddate, '%m/%d/%Y')

# Format the datetime object as a string
formatted_date = datetime_obj.strftime('%Y-%m-%d %H:%M:%S')

print(formatted_date)
```

This code will output:

```
2015-04-25 00:00:00
```