# TypeError: descriptor 'strftime' requires a 'datetime.time' object but received a 'str'

Tags: python, python-2.7

I could run the following lines independently.

```
 import time
 time.strftime("%Y%m%d")
```

Then I put them into one class method I am defining

```
 import time 
 def method(self):
    ...
    [time.strftime("%Y%m%d") for x in range(5)]
    ...
```

The list comprehension has no interaction with other lines.

then, it just threw the following error:

**TypeError: descriptor 'strftime' requires a 'datetime.time' object but received a 'str'**

could anyone give me a hint what is going on? Thank you.

Comment: Could you give us more information (a [mcve]) than "this line of code both works and fails"?

Comment: you might find usefull infos here: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/30112357/typeerror-descriptor-strftime-requires-a-datetime-date-object-but-received

Comment: You've told us you've encountered a mysterious situation in which `strftime` goes haywire, but you haven't told us what that situation _is_.

Comment: Hello, thanks a lot everyone, I have updated the question, is it better now?

Answer (score 1):

I find the solution by the following line:

```
from datetime import time
```

instead of

```
import time
```

Thanks a lot still.