# Type of the received date input from HTML is '<Class 'String'>

Tags: python, html, date, flask

I received the date input from my HTML and willing to split that into year, month and date.
But when I received the date, the type of the date is shown as 'class string' which looks weird.

My Flask Code is:

```
@app.route('/germhourlycon', methods=['POST'])
def germhourlycon():
    from_date=request.form['from']
    to_date=request.form['to']
    print (type(from_date))
return from_date
```

The output is :

```
<class 'str'>
```

HTML Code is:

```
    <form method=POST action="{{ url_for('germhourlycon') }}">
      <input type="date" name="from" placeholder="YYYY-DD-MM">

      <input type="date" name="to" placeholder="YYYY-DD-MM">
      <input type="submit" class="button -green center">
     </form>
```

I followed the following previous thread, but not helpful. When I tried to extract the values from the received input, I could not do it and throws an error

```
TypeError: descriptor 'strftime' requires a 'datetime.date' object but received a 'str'
```

[TypeError: descriptor 'strftime' requires a 'datetime.date' object but received a 'Text'](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/30112357/typeerror-descriptor-strftime-requires-a-datetime-date-object-but-received)

Answer (score 4, accepted):

[`strftime()`](https://docs.python.org/3/library/datetime.html#datetime.datetime.strftime) is used to format a `datetime.datetime` object as a string.

Instead use [`datetime.strptime()`](https://docs.python.org/3/library/datetime.html#datetime.datetime.strptime) to parse the incoming string into a Python `datetime` object:

```
>>> from datetime import datetime
>>> dt = datetime.strptime('2017-10-28', '%Y-%m-%d')
>>> dt
datetime.datetime(2017, 10, 28, 0, 0)
```

You can then convert the `datetime` to a `date`:

```
>>> d = dt.date()
>>> d
datetime.date(2017, 10, 28)
```

Comment: Thanks very much and now I get your details :) (took my 2 days)